How avoid debris collision when moving near lightspeed?
When one is travelling near light speed any collision with (near) stationary objects is a problem. Getting rock to windshield at C will leave one !"#! dent.
One might hit rocks, debris or even nebulae. How might one practically mitigate this problem?
Here's what I've played with and obvious problems:

Alter course: How would one detect small enough objects? Can you do it fast enough?
Armor: Works until it doesn't.
Shields: Accelerating object to move away would cost !#!"# of energy.
Gravity wells or some area projectile shot beforehand to 'plow' the way. Energy inefficient.
Maintained 'highways' by 3rd party. That’s a lot of road to cover.

How avoid debris collision when moving near lightspeed?

Well that's the neat thing, you probably can't avoid debris. Some of your thoughts like with shields or plow may work well enough in a story without going into detail,
pushing things out of the way sounds nice but seems hard to "plow" things away without big booms while also moving very very fast. But just a point that "Energy inefficient" might not be so inefficient where the alternative is "big kaboom on spaceship".

This is a very big problem in real life for speeds much lower than lightspeed. Even at a few kilometers per second, a tiny fleck of paint can prove to be a big problem for the ISS.

ProjectRho is a great resource for this sort of thing. Half way down this page is a section on 'starship bumpers' https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/slowerlight3.php

You don't avoid debris
Outer space is pretty empty, containing only a handful of particles per cubic centimetre.  Unfortunately "pretty empty" is not nearly empty enough: a square metre of ship prow travelling at $0.5c$ sweeps out about 150 million cubic metres of such space, intersecting about $\mathrm{1.5\times10^{14}}$ particles (I love Wolfram Alpha). Those particles are mostly hydrogen or helium, but it doesn't really matter: your prow is dealing with about 10kW of bombardment energy per square metre, wherever it's pointing.  Note that that's the non-relativistic kinetic energy; at $0.5c$ the relativistic correction is about +15%, but at $0.9c$ it's +230% and at $0.99c$ it's a 15-fold increase (accounting for both the greater volume swept, and the much greater energy of the particles you encounter). Sure, in the ludicrously unlikely event that your ship hits a marble instead of a sand grain it'll instantaneously have to deal with a couple of orders of magnitude more impact energy, but that's just surge protection needed on the basic shielding.
Deflection is the only answer
Quite aside from the challenge of building a shield capable of handling a small bomb detonating on its face every second for several years, the wasted energy required to keep the ship moving at relativistic velocities in the face of so much drag makes the plough-through-with-a-big-shield approach impractical.  What you need is to deflect the particles sideways just far, and fast, enough to get them out of the way of the ship as it passes through. We need one hell of a slipstream effect.  A sacrificial projectile is just another type of shield: you shoot it forward, it soaks up some particles, but then either it disintegrates and becomes part of the problem, or it decelerates and slams back into the front of the ship again.  There are already concepts for various magnetic-field-and-laser devices to deflect particles around ships.  A white hole or other negative-gravity object would be effective at clearing space, but would be inefficient and would also tend to accelerate away from the mass of the spacecraft following it, so would need some sort of exotic tether. A regular space lane sweeping service carried out by dredgers towing white holes would actually be a relatively effective solution!

Your math is way off. You plug in 0.5 ly (distance traveled in 1 year) into your linked Wolfram Alpha equation rather than 0.5 c (distance traveled in 1 second), and then perform the rest of the calculations with units of seconds. The kinetic energy I calculate is about 0.002 W/m^2. I calculate a sweeping volume of 150M m^3 per second, and at 1 hydrogen atom per cubic meter, that number of hydrogen atoms per second as well.

Oh wow, that's spectacular :facepalm:

Although it's a few particles per cubic centimetre, not cubic metre, so it's $10^6\times$ more than yours.

Oh right :facepalm:. Lol what's a few measly magnitudes anyway

The OoM of the OoM is correct, so the cosmologists would be happy :-p

Upvote for Wolfram alpha reference in answer.

@BMF You got me researching this and I found that the interstellar medium actually varies by about 10-12 orders of magnitude depending on where you are looking and what sources you cite. The Hot Ionized Medium which makes up  most of the space between solar systems is estimated to have between 1-100 atoms per cubic meter... so your original number is not impossible if you are careful about where you are choosing to fly.

Stick to the "Interstellar Highways" and you will be fine.
Although a lot of sources like to say that the interstellar medium has a density of 1 atom per cubic cm (10,000 per m^3), this is a classical example of an oversimplification of a complex system.  In reality, the interstellar medium ranges from about 100 billion atoms/m^3 in a stellar nurseries down to as little as 1 atom/m^3 in Hot Ionized Medium(HIM).
So let's say you are moving at 0.5c, that is the difference between impacting about 1.5e11 and 1.5e22 atoms per second which gives you a drag of anywhere between 11.3 Newtons and 1130 Giganewtons per square meter. The former being about 1/100th of the drag force experienced by a 747 airliner at normal cruise speeds and altitudes, and the latter being about 10,000 times the resistance experienced by a 747 slamming full throttle into the side of a mountain... so yeah... what path you take in space matters a lot.
Infact, as long as you are sticking to HIM or WIM paths (about 75-90% of known space), you can maintain speeds over half the speed of light without experiencing any exceptional hull stress.  If you have to pass into WNM (about 10-20% of space), you'll want to throttle down to 0.1c-0.2c unless your ship is made out of any special future tech materials.  It's only if you pass into a nebula, stellar nurseries, or CNM (which are together 1-5% of space) that you'd actually need to slow down to sub-relativistic speeds to survive.

This is why star trek ships have a "deflector".
this is indeed some kind of EM shield generator (but not the combat shields) that is the equivalent of the big plow on old-west trains. it nudges anything in front of the ship to the side to prevent collissions.
These deflector fields don't fully move the object, but just gently 'nudge' it to the side. juuuuust far enough to dodge.
it takes a lot of energy, sure. since it's a passive system (turn on and done), it is the safest and most relyable. as long as you can supply it with power

This would require very intense field. I'd need to accelerate the object fast enough. Also the direction is an issue. Far away it's pushing it 'same way as ship' and only close you get sideways push.

If the system needs power then it is not passive by definition. Set and forget would have probably been a more accurate characterization.

The problem with any kind of deflector, that is based on something moving at the speed of light, means it has a real hard time getting out in from of the ship moving at close to speed of light. It takes time to move something out of the way, and that means distance when traveling... especially close to the speed of light.

@ThisIsMe What you call " the big plow on old-west trains." is called a cowcatcher.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowcatcher

I think if you're using warp drive technology, where you're bending spacetime to achieve your relativistic velocities, you could bend it even further so that you're going in between particles. So not only do you move crazy fast, you also get crazy small.

An alternative option to the "shove it aside as you go" answer that is the go-to so far:
You go right through it as if it doesn't exist, because in your local frame of reference, it doesn't.
Many FTL technologies in sci-fi are based on the ship being in some sort of "bubble" that protects from the relativistic effects otherwise seen when attempting to travel through "normal" space-time. Star Trek uses the "warp bubble", essentially bending spacetime around the ship to create a conduit through which the ship moves at FTL speed while actually standing still in the pocket of spacetime immediately surrounding the ship.
The ST universe still posits that anything in the path of the ship and its bubble can enter the bubble and thus physically impact the ship, necessitating the "deflector array" whose primary purpose is to turn aside relatively small meteoroids and space dust, while the ship's navigators avoid anything much larger through course selection and skillful maneuvering.
The Orville universe, Seth McFarlane's nod to ST while not overtly infringing Paramount's IP from the Fox/Disney umbrella, instead uses the concept of a  "quantum bubble", handwaving quantum physics to explain that the ship is isolated from normal spacetime, passing through it without interacting with it as normal matter would. In this universe, "deflectors" are shields against weapons; the quantum bubble itself prevents ordinary matter from contacting the ship while underway, by simple virtue of the ship passing right through the spacetime containing that matter without disturbing it.
The bubble is also what prevents relativistic effects on the ship (and thus allows true FTL travel), and this is pointed out in a Season 3 episode where the Orville travels back in time. Long story short, the device that enabled that trip burns out when going back in time, but the chief engineer realizes that they don't need it to go forward in time. All they need to do is to travel at near-light speed, without the quantum bubble protecting them from the relativistic effects of travelling through normal spacetime at that speed. When doing that, they fortify the deflector shields to protect against small debris, and the trip they need is relatively close in the grand scheme (200 light years one-way) so a fairly clear course can be charted.
Other FTL technologies, such as space-folding, wormholes etc, could be described as having a similar advantage; the ship isn't what's moving, and the way space moves around it precludes the possibility of collision with matter in the normal spacetime between origin and destination. Any of these could be used to handwave not only how FTL travel is possible, but why running into a pebble in space at relativistic speeds isn't a problem; it isn't even a possibility.

Another similiar idea I read in a book (I dont remember which one) was that the warp bubble while containing the whole ship on the inside is tiny on the outside. In the order of an atomic nucleus.
So while it can collide with things, the cross section is so tiny that its practically irrelevant.
Supposedly that also helps bringing the required energy to create the bubble in the first place down to something manageable.

If a space opera spacecraft has gravity generators, the gravity generators can make the "downward" direction point wherever the builders desire, which in turn will require the floors or decks to be orientated perpendicular to the downward direction from the generated gravity.
In some written space operas, and most movie and tv space operas like Star Trek and Star Wars, space ships have a layout similar to sea ships.  The decks run fore and aft, parallel to the direction of travel, while the direction of down created by the generated gravity is perpendicular to the decks and thus to the direction of travel.
And suppose the starship has to suddenly accelerate or decelerate.  The crew members will tend to be thrown suddenly forwards or backwards and be in danger of turning into splatters of blood and internal organs on the bulkheads they might be thrown against.  And possibly the superfast computers on the ship can prevent the crew (and themselves) from being smashed by rapidly adjusting the strength and direction of the generated gravity so that the total forces felt by the crew (and equipment) have the same intensity and vector as always.
And in the usual sea ship based design of spaceships the direction of the generated gravity is perpendicular to the direction of travel, so if the ship suddenly accelerates or decelerates and there is a strong force pulling forward or backwards that strong force will be perpendicular to the generated gravity.  That means that the supercomputers will not only have to instantly adjust the positive or negative strength of the generated gravity but also instantly adjust its vector, in order to avoid the crew and the computers being smashed.  And if the gravity generators can't switch their direction fast enough the crew and equipment will be splattered against bulkheads.
But if the spaceship's decks are stacked one above the other and are oriented perpendicular to the direction of travel, the direction of "down" provided by generated gravity will be parallel to the direction of travel.  So if the ship suddenly decelerates and a force tries to pull the crew toward the ceilings, the gravity generators might increase their power so that the crew will still experience a net 1 g of force holding them down in their seats.  And if the space ship suddenly accelerates at 1,000 g, the gravity generators might be able to switch to producing a negative 999 g so that the crew will still experience a net 1 g of force holding them down in their seats.
It is perfectly possible that changing the direction of the generated gravity might take much longer time than changing the amount of the generated gravity.  Which means that the ship's computers might not be able to react to sudden acceleration or deceleration fast enough to keep the crew or the computers intact.
From an engineering view, it is much more sensible to build space opera space ships with gravity generators with tall, narrow shapes, with many decks stacked one above the other like floors in a skyscraper.
And it seems to me that the narrower the spaceship, the smaller the cross section that is exposed to collisions.
Suppose that there is no generated gravity.  In that case a space ship or starship might accelerate steadily at 1 g, or close enough to it, until it is halfway to the destination, and then flip over to decelerate at the same g force for the second half of the journey.  Thus the ship's acceleration and deceleration would provide the feeling and direction of gravity during the voyage except maybe during the flip over period halfway. The direction of down provided by the engines would always be toward the rear of the ship and away from the front of the ship.
But what if the spaceship doesn't have enough fuel to accelerate and decelerate the entire journey?  In that case it will be coasting the for most of the trip, and there will be no feeling of gravity for most of the trip.  And if the voyage lasts long enough the lack of gravity could cause health problems for the crew.
One solution would be to rotate the ship along its long axis when it was not under thrust.  One end of the ship would have about 1 g simulated gravity for the crew quarters.  The ship would have to stop rotating to make any course corrections and to decelerate at the end of the voyage.
From what I have read engineers think that is a rather complex and undesirable design.
So maybe the ship will have to rotate around its long axis to provide simulated gravity.  If the ship is cylindrical in shape, the inner side of the outer hull will be the "lowest" deck, and possibly the only deck with strong enough gravity if the ship is very narrow.
The problem is that the cylindrical ship should be as narrow as possible to present as small a cross section as possible to incoming space matter.  But the smaller the radius of the rotating cylinder, the more likely the passengers are suffer bad effects from rotating rapidly.
So I can imagine a space ship many thousands of feet long and tall, and either 100 or 1,000 feet in diameter.
Imagine that in the spaceship only 100 feet in diameter only the ring within 10 feet of the outer hull will have the right gravity for human habitation when it is spinning. The ship will have a radius of 50 feet and the area where the gravity is loo low for humans will have a radius of 40 feet.
The area of the circular cross section through the ship will be 7,854 square feet.  And the area of the circular cross section of the ship where the simulated gravity will be too low will be 5,026 Square feet.  Thus only abut 2,828 of the 7,854 square feet will have the correct gravity for long range human habitation while the ship is spinning.  So about 0.3599 of the ship's cross section will be directly usable by the crew, but all of the ship's cross section will be a target for incoming particles.
https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/area-of-a-circle
So possibly the ship could be a hollow cylinder, with an outer radius of 50 feet and an inner void with a radius of 40 feet, where there is no matter for incoming particles to strike.
Imagine a ship with a diameter of 1,000 feet and radius of 500 feet.  Suppose that the 100 feet closest to the outer wall have the right gravity when rotating and have several decks. Thus there can be an inner void with a radius of 400 feet.  Thus the ship will have a circular cross section of 785,398 square feet, minus the 502,655 square feet of the inner void, for a total cross section of 282,743 square feet exposed to incoming particles.
And I hope that the best size for a ship of that design will have a diameter somewhere between those extremes.
So if the ship's thrust provides simulated gravity while the ship is accelerating and decelerating, the simulated gravity will thus be along the axis of the ship's movement. And while the ship is not under thrust and is rotating the simulated gravity will be be outward from the central axis of the ship and thus at right angles to the direction of the ship's travel.
So in different modes, the direction of "down" resulting from simulated gravity will be at different angles, perpendicular to each other. Which will make the design of the crew's living quarters interesting.
The RP FLIP (Floating Instrument Platform) in use from 1962 to 2017 could change its vertical orientation by 90 degrees.
"The platform was 108 meters (355 ft) long and was designed to partially flood and pitch backward 90°, resulting in only the front 17 meters (55 ft) of the platform pointing up out of the water, with bulkheads becoming decks. When flipped, most of the buoyancy for the platform was provided by water at depths below the influence of surface waves, hence FLIP was stable and mostly immune to wave action, similar to a spar buoy. At the end of a mission, compressed air was pumped into the ballast tanks in the flooded section and the platform, which had no propulsion, returned to its horizontal position so it could be towed to a new location.[7]"
"The ship had specially designed interiors: some fixtures, such as the toilet seats, could flip 90°, and the shower heads were curved 90°. There were overhead lights on the surfaces that were the ceilings in both the towing (horizontal) and flipped orientations."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_FLIP
So such a spaceship might have dual orientation living quarters like FLIP for short missions.  But a ship for missions lasting years, decades, centuries, or millennia should have two sets of living quarters with different orientations, one for when the ship was under thrust and one for when it was not under thrust and was rotating.
Or possibly the ship could have many different sets of spherical living quarters on gimbals so they could turn and change their orientation. In the orientation for thrust, "down" in the living quarters would be parallel to the direction of travel. In the orientation for rotation for simulated gravity, "down" in the living quarters would be toward the outer hull of the rotating ship.
And in a more scientifically advanced but rather less plausible space opera setting,  the ship could have generated gravity pulling "down" along the long axis of the ship and its direction of travel.
Thus the ship would have to be wide enough for the circular decks to wide enough for use, and otherwise it should be as now as possible to present as small a cross section as possible to incoming particles.
Obviously heroic space explorers might be willing to live in a ship where each deck was only ten or a dozen feet in diameter with a spiral staircase in the center and very cramped living quarters on the sides, and for months and years at a time.
But passengers in a space liner would prefer that the decks had much wider diameters, like fifty or a hundred feet, with room for elevators and stars, and radial and circular corridors and decently size cabins.
And families living in a generation ship for their entire lives would probably want a much wider ship for at least some large interior spaces like dining halls, swimming pools, religious structures, schools, courthouses, etc.
Of course if the ship's propulsion machinery has a minimum width the ship must be at least that wide, at least in the propulsion section.
Possibly the ship could taper with a slight slope between the narrowest and the widest sections.  And possibly the ship could emit a repulsive force which pushed away charged particles.  And possibly the narrowest leading sections of the ship could push away particles fast enough that they don't strike the following wider sections.
"A pencil tower (also known as a skinny skyscraper,1 pencil-thin tower, super-slender tower, or super-slim tower) is a high-rise building or skyscraper with a very high slenderness ratio that is very tall and thin.2 There is no universal definition of how slender these buildings are to be categorized, but some definitions of 10:1 or 12:1 ratios and higher have been used.4"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_tower
The Steinway Tower or 111 West 57th Street, in New York City is one of the most horrifying things I have ever seen in photos, an d I have seen some gruesome photos I try to forget.
"The residential tower atop Steinway Hall is one of the tallest buildings in the United States, as well as the thinnest skyscraper in the world with a width-to-height ratio of about 1:24.[25][26][27][b] Due to its slenderness, the top stories sway several feet during high winds.[14]"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/111_West_57th_Street#
And that gives an idea of the possible slenderness of a spaceship travelling at high velocities. Maybe a hundred feet in diameter with a cross section of 7,8540 square feet, and being 2,000 to 3,000 feet tall.
In chapter twelve of A.E. Van Vogt's Mission to the Stars or The Mixed Men, the mighty space battleship Star Cluster runs into a space "storm", probably a nebula, at a speed of half a light year per minute, or 525,960 times the speed of light, and at such speeds running into such an incredibly thin vacuum was like ramming into a brick wall.
The stress on the great ship becomes too great.

She began to break up.
And still everything was according to the original purpose of the the suburb engineering firm which had built her.  The limit of her unit strain reached, she dissolved into her nine thousand separate sections.
Streamlined slivers of metal were those sections, four hundred feet long, forty feet wide; silverlike shapes sinuated cunningly through the gases, letting the pressure of them slide off their smooth sides.

https://archive.org/details/missiontostarsor0000vanv/page/101/mode/1up
So I can imagine a space ship which has many slender parts attached side by side as it travelled slowly.  And after accelerating to a speed where striking particles in space is a problem, and then cutting off the engines to coast for the rest of the voyage, the many slender parts would detach from each other and reattach in a different configuration, end to end.
So this new end to end configuration the ship might be only 100 feet in diameter and a thousand times that long as it coasts for most of the voyage.  thus it would greatly reduce its vulnerable cross section for most of the voyage.
And possibly a robot space ship might be able to have much thinner sections and be only a foot in diameter and a million feet long when coasting in end to end configuration.

This has already been solved.
You're not moving at close to the speed of light, that's not possible.
You are stationary and the universe is moving, but, and this is the important bit. At that speed it's a potential universe, so as far as you and it are concerned neither is corporeal to the other. You can have a potential planet pass through you and not feel it. The danger time is when you're going slower relative to each other and are no longer just 'potentials'.

That's an ..... interesting take. Also where might i get some of that also? ;)

Hehe, it would be a fun solution to play around with, once things are moving fast enough relative to each other they're just potentials. Because known physics has already broken down. If I'm moving towards a guy at light speed and I fire a gun at him, Then the bullet is faster than light?... not possible... so it's just a potential
